# How to filter by slug in notion api

Tags: javascript, next.js, notion-api

I am trying to get a page from a database in notion through the slug, but when filtering it gives me an error
the error is:

```sh
@notionhq/client warn: request fail {
  code: 'validation_error',
  message: 'body failed validation. Fix one:\n' +
    'body.filter.formula.string should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\n' +
    'body.filter.formula.checkbox should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\n' +
    'body.filter.formula.number should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\n' +
    'body.filter.formula.date should be defined, instead was `undefined`.'
}
```

i use next.js

my controller is notion.js:

```js
export async function getSingleBlogPost(slug) {
  const database = process.env.NOTION_BLOG_DATABASE_ID ?? '';

  // list of blog posts
  const response = await client.databases.query({
    database_id: database,
    filter: {
      property: 'Slug',
      formula: {
        text: {
          equals: slug, // slug
        },
      },
      // add option for tags in the future
    },
    sorts: [
      {
        property: 'Updated',
        direction: 'descending',
      },
    ],
  });

  if (!response.results[0]) {
    throw 'No results available';
  }

  const page = response.results[0];
  const mdBlocks = await n2m.pageToMarkdown(page.id);
  const post = await pageToPostTransformer(page);
  const markdown = n2m.toMarkdownString(mdBlocks);

  return {
    post,
    markdown,
  };
}
```

for more code of my file view: https://pastebin.com/RapTGN38

in my [slug].jsx:

```js
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";
import Head from "next/head";

import {getSingleBlogPost, getPublishedBlogPosts} from '../../lib/notion.js'

const Post = ({markdown, post}) => {
    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>{post.title}</title>
                <meta name={"description"} title={"description"} content={post.description}/>
                <meta name={"og:title"} title={"og:title"} content={post.title}/>
                <meta name={"og:description"} title={"og:description"} content={post.description}/>
                <meta name={"og:image"} title={"og:image"} content={post.cover}/>
            </Head>

            <div className="min-h-screen">
                <main className="max-w-5xl mx-auto relative">
                    <div className="flex items-center justify-center">
                        <article className="prose">
                            <ReactMarkdown>{markdown}</ReactMarkdown>
                        </article>
                    </div>
                </main>
            </div>

        </>
    )
}

export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {

    // @ts-ignore
    const p = await getSingleBlogPost(context.params?.slug)

    if (!p) {
        throw ''
    }

    return {
        props: {
            markdown: p.markdown,
            post: p.post
        },
    }
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {

    const posts = await getPublishedBlogPosts()

    // Because we are generating static paths, you will have to redeploy your site whenever
    // you make a change in Notion.
    const paths = posts.map(post => {
        return `/post/${post.slug}`
    })

    return {
        paths,
        fallback: false,
    }
}

export default Post;
```

i want to make my personal blog, when i open a link of a post, I receive this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liendo, I hope I'm not too late for your problem !

If you read carrefully the notion API error, it give you the answer :

```
Fix one:\n' +
'body.filter.formula.string should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\n' +
'body.filter.formula.checkbox should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\n' +
'body.filter.formula.number should be defined, instead was `undefined`.\n' +
'body.filter.formula.date should be defined, instead was `undefined`.'
```

So it's mean in your filter, in the `formula` object, you need to replace `text` with one of the attributes above (`string` or `checkbox` or `number` or `date`) because one of them need to be defined.
I guess your slug is a `string` type, so your filter will be :

```
filter: {
      property: 'Slug',
      formula: {
        string: {
          equals: slug,
        },
      },
    },
```

It should worked !